# Find and replace not changing list

Tags: python, list

This is my List, I want to change the occurrences of 'b' to 'z', and print. but when I execute the below code, it prints back my original list, what is the issue, no syntax error, some logic error, which I am not able to identify.

```
x = ['1','2','3','4','a','b','b','c','b','b']

for i,y in enumerate(x):
    if y == 'b':
        x[i] = 'z'  # I tried x.append('z'), as well
    else:
        break
print(x)
```

Comment: remove the else condition. It breaks the loop at index 0

Comment: Please see [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  A couple of simple `print` statements will show the operation of your loop.

Comment: thx Prune, I am a complete newbie with no help other than Udemy Course, not even able to understand how debug works in pycharm, hence went back to Jnotebook. I very much knew before posting this is such a kinder garden stuff, but udemy didn't reply, so had to post here in Ph.d standard portal. my appologsis, yes I very much understand this, if you allow these kind of queries, your website will be clogged with inane questions and you end up teaching. thx for the cue's on debugging tools let me try using them...cheers...

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead

```py
for i,y in enumerate(x):
    if y == 'b':
        x[i] = 'z'
print(x)
```

`break` breaks out of the loop and stops it completely.

Comment: Yes Chief it worked, thx a many, so I shouldn't use Break for if else? only for while, is that right?

Comment: You can do that, it just depends on the situation. In this case you want to replace each occurrence of a letter, as such you would want to check every element. However, if you just wanted to search for a given element, then you would break once you found it.